# Foundry Palantir - Typescript function : update valeur on columns

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry

I will like a help for a typescript function on ontology object.
I would like to write a typescript program that takes a dataframe as input.
When I remove a value from a row in a column, the values in other columns change to null.

For example, this a dataframe

| ID | level | responsible | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A12 | level2 | NG34Jean | Sheet |
| B15 | level5 | NG90Elis | Bellow |
| C67 | level4 | NG64Matire | Clamp |
| H65 | level3 | NG45Louis | Cubical |
| J90 | level0 | NG08Marie | Blech |

```
For the ID = B15, I would like to remove its level ie "level5" hence the values of "responsible" and "description" egal to "Null"

For the ID = H65, I would like to remove its level ie "level3" hence the values of "responsible" and "description" egal to "Null"
```

Here is the dataframe at the end

| ID | level | responsible | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A12 | level2 | NG34Jean | Sheet |
| B15 | **No value** | *null* | *null* |
| C67 | level4 | NG64Matire | Clamp |
| H65 | **No value** | *null* | *null* |
| J90 | level0 | NG08Marie | Blech |

```
@OntologyEditFunction()
    public async deletevaluetable(
        objectpart: ObjectPartsNew[],
        ID?: string,
        level?: string,
        responsible?: string,
        description?: string,
    ): Promise<void> {
        function deletevaluetable()  {
            var manual;
            for (var i = 0; i < objectpart.length; i++) {
                manual=objectpart[i];
                var updates = 0;
                const properties_dict: manualUpdate = {
                    "manual": ID, 
                };
                .....
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing some concepts, for example editing the ontology is not a spark job, thus there are no dataframes. You're directly manipulating an individual objects entity in a real time search and indexing system. Any chance you can show the code that actually  performs the changes?  I have a suspicion you are just overwriting the previous entity with a new one with less columns.

i.e. instead of this:

```
   manual=objectpart[i];
   var updates = 0;
   const properties_dict: manualUpdate = {
       "manual": ID, 
   };
```

You probably want:

```
   const editedObjectProperties: ObjectPartsNew = {
       ID: ID, 
       level: "No value",
       responsible: objectpart[i].responsible,
       description: objectpart[i].description
   };
```

Comment: Please, how do to increment [i] ?

At the end, the value of responsible and description are "null". Thanks

Comment: `i` is already being incremented in your for loop within your original code

Comment: ok, thanks, I understand
but "objectpart[i].responsible" and "objectpart[i].description" does this mean that the values of responsible and description are set to "null" ?